# How to join two cache into the Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

I need to join two list cached into my Model, to build a new cached list

I've tried the code below but `cached_groups` is producing an empty result. Any ideas?

```
  def cached_favgroups
    Rails.cache.fetch([self, "fav_groups"]) {fav_groups.to_a}
  end

  def cached_groups_all
    Rails.cache.fetch([self, "groups"])
  end

  def cached_groups
    Rails.cache.fetch(self.cached_groups_all - self.cached_favgroups )
  end
```

Comment: What specifically is not working.

Comment: Well there is nothing into the cache, When I want to use the code current_user.cached_groups, there is nothing inside. While there should be something. So I suppose that the syntax is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a block to the `fetch` method.   Try this:

```
def cached_groups
  Rails.cache.fetch([self, "groups_all_favgroups"]) do
    self.cached_groups_all - self.cached_favgroups 
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @TomAranda for your precious help !! And a last question, do you know a method to expire this caches manually that I can use into my controller ?

Comment: I suggest you read the [Caching with Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html).   There is a [delete method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html) in `Rails.cache` that can do this for you.